# Does Nuxt Auth Module use serverMiddleware or client one?

Tags: authentication, nuxt.js

I want to understand whether nuxt-auth uses serverMiddleware and if not how can i implement one. I want to make my admin panel really secured, I have my backend secured however even if someone manages to overcome auth middleware on the frontend, which won't be that difficult(if auth Module uses client-side middlewares), I don't want nuxt to provide him/her with the layout and all pages even though I know that he/she is not going to be able to do anything because my routes on the backed require token verification and account data. If you can, please provide some info on the subject. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So in short you cannot use the middleware provided by the @nuxtjs/auth plugin as a serverMiddleware, you can only use it as a normal middleware.

But that doesn't mean that it's insecure, normal middlewares actually executes both on server and client side before the page is rendered, so if you want to execute a middleware that will throw a 404 if the user isn't logged in you can do this in a normal middleware too, the serverMiddleware's capabilities are actually limited, you can't access nor the store or any client side information, because you only get (req,res, next) as parameters, and since Authentication is stored in store and cookies you can't make it work in Node.js only. This is a good example of what you can use serverMiddleware for: https://jackwhiting.co.uk/posts/handling-redirects-in-nuxtjs-through-middlware/

If you console.log something in normal middleware you should be able to see it both in your developer console and bash where npm run dev is running, this would mean that first the server executes it and then the client side too.